# text function does not show updated variable

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have the following code:

```
var c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10;

c1=c2=c3=c4=c5=c6=c7=c8=c9=c10=0;

var counters= [c1,c2,c3,c4,c6,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10];



for (var i=0;i<counters.length;i++){
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(25);
    text(counters[i],10+40*i,50); 
//this text function does show the updated counter variable, it stays on 0. Why?
    line(i*40,0,i*40,400);
}




stroke(38, 165, 224);
fill(255, 255, 255);
rect(140,231,120,43);
textSize(25);
fill(0, 0, 0);
text("Play again", 141,258);
mouseClicked= function(){
if (mouseX<150+120 && mouseX>154 && mouseY>231 &&mouseY<231+43){
var randomx=random(0,400);
ellipse(randomx,100,20,20);
if (randomx>=0 && randomx<40){
    c1++;
    println(c1);
} else if(randomx>=40 &&randomx<=80){
c2++;
println(c2);
}
}
};
```

When I click the "play again" button, it should create an ellipse with an x value ranging from 0-400. If the ellipse is created in the first or second column(that is, has an x value of 0-40 or 40-80), I update the corresponding counter variable, in this case c1 or c2.
However, the updated counter variable is not displayed in the text function above the column. It just displays 0, even when the counter variable is updated to 1,2,3 etc. Why is this not working? And how do I make it work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. With `p5.js` it should include a clear `setup()` and `draw()` function. Note that you need something like `draw()` to actually render something to the canvas. Otherwise something like `text()` will just write to a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth stepping back a bit and breaking down the problem into simpler steps. I recommend checking out Kevin Workman's [How to Program](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) guide.

It is worth going over a few basics first. Here some notes based on your code:

- you should strive to format your code: the cleaner it is the easier it is to read. Programming you'll spend more time planning/thinking and reading / debugging code than actually typing instructions. It's well worth making things easy not just for your future self, but also for other trying to understand your code to support
- as you can see in the [p5.js get started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) guide you'll need to use `setup()` to initialise that (as it gets called once) and `draw()` to continously update and render data.
- `println()` is Processing syntax: use `console.log()` in JavaScript

Here's a revised version of your code:

```js
var c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10;
c1=c2=c3=c4=c5=c6=c7=c8=c9=c10=0;
  
var counters = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c6, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10];

var buttonX = 140;
var buttonY = 231;
var buttonW = 121;
var buttonH = 43;
  
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(25);
    text(counters[i], 10 + (40 * i), 50); 
    //this text function does show the updated counter variable, it stays on 0. Why?
    line(i * 40, 0, i * 40, 400);
  }

  stroke(38, 165, 224);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(140, 231, 120, 43);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("Play again", 141, 258);
  // visualise button
  noFill();
  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);
}

mouseClicked = function() {
  if (mouseX < buttonX + buttonW && mouseX > buttonX && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonH) {
    var randomX = random(0, 400);
    ellipse(randomX, 100, 20, 20);
    if (randomX >= 0 && randomX < 40) {
      c1++;
      console.log(c1);
    } else if (randomX >= 40 && randomX <= 80) {
      c2++;
      console.log(c2);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

There are a couple of extra steps missing:

- clearing the background and rendering the updated counters labels (in the version above stuck at 0 as they're only drawn once in `setup()`)
- using separate [PGraphics](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) buffer/"layer" to render and remember the randomX positions rendered as ellipses
- optionally using another `for` loop to check which 40px vertical slice will have it's counter updated. The advantage is avoiding [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,data%20normalization%20to%20avoid%20redundancy.) and making the code more flexibile, should you choose to change the number of counters.

There a couple of extra bits, such as:

- getting rid of manual `c1` to `c10` counters (since the same data is stored in `counters` anyway
- filling the `counters` array with zeros
- storing variables for button coordiantes (making the code easier to read and change)

This is probably closer to what you had in mind:

```js
var numCounters = 10;  
var counters = new Array(numCounters);

var buttonX = 140;
var buttonY = 231;
var buttonW = 121;
var buttonH = 43;

var randomXVisualise;

var sectionWidth = 40;  
  
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900);
  randomXVisualise = createGraphics(900, 900);
  randomXVisualise.noFill();
  // fill the array with zeros
  counters.fill(0);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(25);
    text(counters[i], 10 + (40 * i), 50); 
    //this text function does show the updated counter variable, it stays on 0. Why?
    line(i * sectionWidth, 0, i * sectionWidth, 400);
  }

  stroke(38, 165, 224);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(140, 231, 120, 43);
  textSize(25);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("Play again", 141, 258);
  // visualise button
  noFill();
  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);
  
  image(randomXVisualise, 0, 0);
}

mouseClicked = function() {
  if (mouseX < buttonX + buttonW && mouseX > buttonX && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonH) {
    var randomX = random(0, 400);
    randomXVisualise.ellipse(randomX, 100, 20, 20);
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i < numCounters; i++){
      if (randomX >= sectionWidth * i && randomX < (sectionWidth * (i + 1))) {
        counters[i]++;  
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```